# MySQL get the date n days ago as a timestamp

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how would I get a timestamp from, say 30 days ago?

Something like:

```
select now() - 30
```

The result should return a timestamp.

Comment: I think you are after [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Comment: What format of timestamp ? There's the format people who work with  MySQL DATE functions are familiar with, and there's a UNIX style timestamp.

Comment: I'm after the MySQL Timestamp.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if the answer were as simple as how the OP asked?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

DATE_SUB will do part of it depending on what you want

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day);
2009-06-07 21:55:09

mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day));
2009-06-07 21:55:09

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day));
1244433347
```

Comment: What is the different with the first and second query?

Comment: it appears (v1) DATE_SUB will return a DATETIME or STRING depending on inputs.  TIMESTAMP (v2) is forcing it to a TIMESTAMP type.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(maketime(_,_,_));
```

For unix timestamps or:

```
SELECT addtime(now(),maketime(_,_,_));
```

For the standard MySQL date format.

Answer (score 1):

If you need negative hours from timestamp

```
mysql>SELECT now( ) , FROM_UNIXTIME( 1364814799 ) , HOUR( TIMEDIFF( now( ) , FROM_UNIXTIME( 1364814799 ) ) ) , TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , now( ) , FROM_UNIXTIME( 1364814799 ) ) 
2013-06-19 22:44:15     2013-04-01 14:13:19     1904    -1904
```

this

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , now( ) , FROM_UNIXTIME( 1364814799 ) )
```

will return negative and positive values, if you need to use x>this_timestamp

but this

```
HOUR( TIMEDIFF( now() , FROM_UNIXTIME( 1364814799 ) ) )
```

will return only positive, hours