# MySQL query to show count of rows where date is in the past 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, count

Pretty basic question, I need to show a count of items that were entered 30 days ago (compared to today/current timestamp). Also need to do the same for 60 and 90 days.

I have:

```
$format = 'Y-m-j G:i:s'; 
$d = date( $format, strtotime ( '-30 days' ) );
$db->query_first("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS val FROM ".DB_TABLE."tickets WHERE entered <= '$d'");
```

The *entered* row shows reflects the date the item was keyed into the db (ie 01/01/2012). Need to show a count of the items were entered 30, 60, and 90 days ago.

Not sure if I'm on the right path...

Comment: I personally prefer MySQL's native functions DATE_SUB in combination with CURDATE / CURTIME / NOW. I'd suggest you make three separate queries, and in my opinion you're on the right track.

Comment: What are your ranges? Are they 30 to 59 days, 60 to 89 days, and 90+ days?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can (and should) be done in one query. Try something like this (look at [DATEDIFF() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)) :

```
mysql_query('(
    SELECT 30 AS numDays, count(*) AS numTickets FROM tickets WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), tickets.entered) <= 30
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 60 AS numDays, count(*) AS numTickets FROM tickets WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), tickets.entered) <= 60
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 90 AS numDays, count(*) AS numTickets FROM tickets WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), tickets.entered) <= 90
)');
```

This query will return three rows, indicating the number of tickets for each of the ranges.

Be careful : number of '60-day-old' tickets will contain number of '30-day-old' tickets. You'll have to adapt the query if you want to exclude the different ranges.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL get the date n days ago as a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095831/mysql-get-the-date-n-days-ago-as-a-timestamp)

```
 SELECT count(*) AS val FROM {table} 
 WHERE entered >= TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: (and you can just change the 30 in PHP)

Comment: Using DATEDIFF() function will be less expensive that `entered >= TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)`

Answer (score 0):

This may make your head hurt a bit, but one row with all 3 columns for respective within 30, 31-60 and 61-90 days...

```
SELECT
      sum( if( TK.entered >= @OneMonthAgo, 1, 0 )) CountWithin30,
      sum( if( TK.entered >= @TwoMonthsAgo and TK.entered < @OneMonthAgo, 1, 0 ) as Count31To60,
      sum( if( TK.entered >= @ThreeMonthsAgo and TK.entered < @TwoMonthsAgo, 1, 0 ) as Count61To90
   FROM
      ( @OneMonthAgo := date_sub( Now(), Interval 30 day ),
        @TwoMonthsAgo := date_sub( @OneMonthAgo, Interval 30 day ),
        @ThreeMonthsAgo := date_sub( @TwoMonthsAgo, Interval 30 day ) ) SqlVars,
      DB_TABLE.tickets TK
   where
      TK.entered >= date_sub( now(), interval 90 day)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a date-friendly column for the ticket entry (timestamp/date), you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `DB_TABLE` 
WHERE DATE(`rowtimestamp`) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

This is easily modifiable for 60 and 90 as separate queries (or OR'ed), as well as using less-than (<) in case you don't want it so strictly selected.

Comment: This would only select dates that were exactly 30 days ago.

Comment: The OP is unclear about the specific results required by his query.  For adding 60/90, a simple OR will allow showing the additional results in the same query.