# Displaying daily totals between now and x days ago using MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table called 'orders' and it contains; id, order_total and time fields. 'time' is an integer and stores a unix timestamp...

orders

```
| id | order_total  | time          |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 42.00        | 1443355834    |
| 2  | 13.00        | 1443460326    |
| 3  | 51.00        | 1443468094    |
| 4  | 16.00        | 1443477442    |
| 5  | 10.00        | 1443606966    |
| 6  | 53.00        | 1443608256    |
```

I want to able to display in a table using php the sum, of 'order_total' for each day for the previous 'x' amount of days (or weeks or months) so it will look something like this:

```
| Date      | Order Total |
---------------------------
| 27/09/15  | 42.00       |
| 28/09/15  | 80.00       |
| 30/09/15  | 63.00       |
```

I have made a MYSQL query and a php loop that kind of works but being new to MYSQL I am probably over-complicating things and there must be an easier way to do this ? When I say kind of works, it will correctly sum and show the order_totals up until the current day but for some reason will combine the current day with the previous day.

Here is what I currently have:

```
$x = $interval;
$y = $x - 1;

while ($x > 0) {
    $sql10 = "
        SELECT id,
               time,
               SUM(order_total) as sum,
               date_format(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME($now_time), INTERVAL $x DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') as thedate  
         FROM $ordersTABLE 
        WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time) BETWEEN date_format(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME($now_time), INTERVAL $x DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') 
          AND date_format(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME($now_time), INTERVAL $y DAY),'%Y-%m-%d')";

    $result10 = mysql_query ( $sql10, $cid ) or die ( "Couldn't execute query." );

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result10) ) {
        $order_total = $row ["order_total"];
        $thedate = $row ["thedate"];
        $sum = $row ["sum"];
        $sum = number_format($sum,2);
        $thedate = strtotime($thedate);
        $thedate = date("d/m/y",$thedate);

        print "<tr><td width=\"120\">$thedate</td><td>\$$sum</td></tr>";
    }

    $x--;
    $y--;
}
```

(The string $now_time contains the current time as a Unix Timestamp hence the converting as the system time can not be changed and this contains the correct local time for the user)

Is there  better way to do this ?

Comment: try this [ONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064516/selecting-rows-in-the-last-5-minutes-using-unix-time-stamp) and [TWO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095831/mysql-get-the-date-n-days-ago-as-a-timestamp)

Comment: What do you mean, "kind of" works? Does it work, or does it not work? Fair warning, if your code works to your spec/requirements, it's usually off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the timestamps into YYYY MM DD using [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function and then select only the ones which are older enough thanks to the [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function. Today's date is provided by [CURDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function.

First of all, the query which retrieves the totals for the orders older then the interval and reformats the date fields:

```
$q1 = "SELECT " . $ordersTABLE . ".order_total AS total, FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $ordersTABLE . ".time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS short_date FROM " . $ordersTABLE . " WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), short_date) > " . $intervalInDAYS;
```

Then, the one that sums up the totals of the day:

```
$q2 = "SELECT short_date AS day, SUM(total) AS total FROM (" . $q1 . ") GROUP BY short_date";
```

And then you perform your query stored in `$q2` and all other operations you need to display the result.
Result from the query should be in form:

```
|    day    |    total    |
===========================
| 25/09/15  |  34.00      |
| 16/09/15  | 100.00      |
| 31/07/14  |   3.20      |
|    ...    |     ...     |
```