# Date Functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

Looking for some help regarding mysql date functions.

I am looking to show data for a time period of today to 8 days ago (I have been using this line of code in mysql `WHERE TIME > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY` ) ) as well as the above time period but one year ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL get the date n days ago as a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095831/mysql-get-the-date-n-days-ago-as-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using
[**DATE_SUB**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) with [**TIMESTAMPDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff),

`TIMESTAMP` syntax,

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr1, datetime_expr2);
```

`DATE_SUB` syntax,

```
DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL value unit);
```

---

Example,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_SUB('2018-06-04 22:59:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY), 
 '2018-06-04 22:59:00');
```